# How to calculate the time complexity of a recursive solution?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

I am solving [word break problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/) and I have used Dynamic Programming to optimise it, and the solution is working as well. But I am not able to calculate/figure out the time complexity of this approach.

Code:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int util(string &s, int i, unordered_set<string> &dict, vector<int> &DP) {
        if(i >= s.size()) {
            return 1;
        }
        if(DP[i] != -1) {
            return DP[i];
        }
        string next = "";
        for(int itr = i; itr < s.size(); itr++) { // O(N)
            next += s[itr];
            if(dict.find(next) != dict.end() and util(s, itr+1, dict, DP)) { // ?
                return DP[i] = 1;
            }
        }
        return DP[i] = 0;
    }
    
    bool wordBreak(string s, vector<string>& wordDict) {
        unordered_set<string> dict(wordDict.begin(), wordDict.end());
        vector<int> DP(s.size() + 1, -1);
        return util(s, 0, dict, DP);
    }
};
```

Could anyone please help me to understand the time complexity of the above algorithm step-by-step?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `i ∈ [0..n)` (`n` is length of `s`), your recursive function executes full inner loop exactly once (since the second time the result will be cached in `DP`).

At this point you might say that the whole algorithm is O(n²), but that is not true, there is a twist.

The inner loop which you labeled O(n) is not actually O(n), but O(n²), because you're searching `next` (substring of `s`) in the `unordered_dict`. Each such search takes `O( next.length )` time, and, since length of `next` ranges from `0..length(s)`, the dict search is O(n), and the inner loop, consequently is O(n²).

Given all of the above, the whole algorithm is O(n³):  O(n) from recursion and multiplied by O(n²) from inner loop.

Or, to be precise, O(n³ + k), where `k` is the cummulative size of all strings in the `wordDict` (since you're constructing set from them).

---

P.S. To reduce complexity by factor of O(n) you can use [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) instead of `unordered_set` to store words from `wordDict`. With that your algorithm would be O(n² + k).